# Apache WebServer redirecting to 404 if URL contains Arabic characters

Tags: apache, url, encoding, arabic

We are using CMS tool with Tomcat & Apache for Multilingual site.
Sometime files or content URL will contain Arabic characters.

On Tomcat Level Arabic Character URLs are working fine. But if we try to access the same page through Apache WebServer URL then we are getting 404 Error.

I added below Characterset in WebServer VitualHost entry but still getting issue. Kindly please help to resolve this issue.

```
AddCharset ISO-8859-1  .iso8859-1  .latin1
AddCharset WINDOWS-1251 .cp-1251   .win-1251
AddCharset UTF-8       .utf8
AddCharset utf-8       .utf8
```

[http://qutomcat:8080/sites/ar/about/الطلبة](http://qutomcat:8080/sites/ar/about/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A9)    [WORKING]

[http://quweb.tst.qa/sites/ar/about/الطلبة](http://quweb.tst.qa/sites/ar/about/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A9)     [NOT WORKING]

Also in the browser getting below Message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sites/ar/about/Ø§ÙØ·ÙØ¨Ø©

Type Status report

message /sites/sites/ar/about/Ø§ÙØ·ÙØ¨Ø©

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Thanks

Jayaram

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Tomcat uses ISO-8859-1 character encoding when decoding
>   URLs received from a browser. This can cause problems when
>   Confluence's encoding is UTF-8, and you are using international
>   characters in the names of attachments or pages.

To configure the URL encoding in Tomcat:
Edit conf/server.xml and find the line where the Coyote HTTP Connector is defined. It will look something like this, possibly with more parameters:

```
 <Connector port="8090"/>
```

Add a URIEncoding="UTF-8"property to the connector:

```
 <Connector port="8090" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Restart Tomcat

[ref](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-url-encoding-on-tomcat-application-server-174898.html)